# Erasing an item from Session array with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have 2 files: `compare.php` (further mentioned as C) and `compare-ajax.php` (C-A).

The part that adds item id to session and display them on a table works fine,
 **but I don't know why it doesn't erase the id (mentioned in the anchor element) from the Session array.**

**C**:

```
1            <?php $session_start(); ?>
2            ....(some php,html code)
3    <script>
4    $( "#options" ).change(function() {
5       $cid= $("#options").val();
6           $("#teste").html($cid);
7           });

8    $(document).ready(function(){
9      $("#submitSearch").click(function(){
10      event.preventDefault(); // f important
11       $.post("compare-ajax.php",
12        {  cid:$cid },
13        function(data){
14          alert ("test");
15          //var tds = $(originalTable).children('tr').children('td').length;
16              $("table tr").html("<td>"+data+"</td>");
17        });
18      });
19    });
20    </script>
...
```

**C-A**:(whole file)

```
<?php
1           session_start();
2       require "config.php"; 

3           if (!isset($_SESSION['cid'])) {
4               $comp_id=array();
5               $_SESSION['cid']=array();
6               array_push($_SESSION['cid'],$_REQUEST['cid']);
7               $comp_id = $_SESSION['cid'];
8           }else {
9               $comp_id=$_SESSION['cid'];
10              if (isset($_REQUEST['cid'])){
11                  if (!is_numeric(array_search($_REQUEST['cid'],$_SESSION['cid']))){
12                      if (count($comp_id)<=3) {  // max number of items (ok)
13                          array_push($_SESSION['cid'],$_REQUEST['cid']);
14                          $comp_id = $_SESSION['cid'];
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

15    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove'])){
16      alert ($rem);
17      $rem=array_search($_REQUEST['remove'],$_SESSION['cid']);
18      if ($rem>=0) {
19      echo "Erasing!";
20          array_splice($_SESSION['cid'], $rem, 1);
21          $comp_id=$_SESSION['cid'];
        }
    }

22      echo "No of elements: ".count($_SESSION['cid']);

23      foreach ($comp_id as $item){                                        
24          echo "<b>".$item."</b> || ";
25          $qu="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM car_tb WHERE c_id=".$item;
26          foreach ($dbo->query($qu) as $r) {
27              $t=1;
28                  echo '<a id="test" href="'.$r[0].'">(('.$r[0].'))</a> ';
29              while ($t<=69):   // max no. of elements for each item
30                  echo "((".$r[$t].")) ";
31                  $t=$t+1;
32              endwhile;
            }
        }

    ?>
33    <script>
34      $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
35      event.preventDefault();
36      var r_id = $(this).attr("href");
37          $.post("compare-ajax.php",
38        {  remove: r_id },
39        function(data){
40          alert ("test "+r_id);
41          alert ("This "+r_id+ " should be removed!");
42              $("table tr").append("<td>"+data+"</td>");
        });
    });
43    </script>
```

Needed: when I click the link (created on line 28 in C-A), the value that is in its *href* I want to be erased/removed from session.
My problem is here: when I click the link(see line 28 in C-A) which is supposed to erase the corresponding id, I get the alert with the correct value, but nothing is erased from the session. I don't even get the alert (line 19 in C-A).

Comment: doesn't work how? You get "erasing" as text, but the thing you're erasing doesn't disappear? Or you don't get erasing at all, which means you're not even GETTING to the erase code.

Comment: alert() is not a native PHP function. Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, Len_D. It seems i missed that during checking...

Answer (score 0):

I see some questionable code, but let's start with the "C" file. It appears you are assigning the "cid" variable to what appears to be a php variable "$cid". This won't work unless you change $cid to  if it's numeric. If "$cid" is a string, then change that to  to have php wrap it in quotes. Of course, make sure $cid is assigned something! Start there and let me know how you make out.